# Weird cookie issue with Silverlight, WCF and Windows 8

Tags: asp.net, wcf, session, cookies, membership

I've been working on this Silverlight app for quite a while now. I have two dev machines. One has windows 7 and the other has windows 8. The SL app implements authentication through WCF and an implementation of MS membership engine. All was working well until I installed win8 on the other machine. Now, when I authenticate from this machine I get the cookie information back but any further request to the server is sent without the cookie information. It doesn't matter which browser I use and what my internet settings are (privacy/security levels all set to lowest... still same issue).

I looked at the requests on fiddler and compared between the two machines. They both send the same requests when logging in and the both receive similar data including the "Set-Cookie" header. The next request however, isn't similar. One machine sends this .ASPXAUTH cookie along with the ASP.NET_SessionId one and the other sends only the ASP.NET_SessionId. It's like it ignored the Set-Cookie command.

Any ideas how to solve this? I tried everything on my internet settings and nothing seems to make a difference.

Thanks,
Eyal

Comment: What are the exact Set-Cookie strings? Is HTTPONLY or SECURE specified? Do you specify any P3P headers?

Comment: Sorry for the huge delay in response. I am no longer working on this project. Don't have access to the server side. I'll update if this becomes relevant again.